# Trouble with new View Controller called from a UITextField Xcode

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6, hyperlink

In the current App that I am writing, I have a UITextField that has a link in it.  So I want to call a new View Controller instead of Safari.  I can have it open in Safari, but I don't want the user to leave my App.  I have done some research and am doing the following.

I made a new file called MyApplication and placed the following inside the .m file to override openURL

```
#import "MyApplication.h"

@implementation MyApplication

- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
if ([self handleOpenURL:url])
    return YES;
else
    return [super openURL:url];
}
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"71"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

return YES;
}

@end
```

In the attributes inspector under View Controller I called the Title 71.  I also called the storyboard ID and restoration ID 71 just to be sure!  In the main.m file I have replaced the third nil with @"MyApplication"  as you can see.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyApplication", NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

However, the App fails to build because in the method handleOpenURL I am getting an error on the line

```
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It says No visible @interface for 'MyApplication' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'  All the samples and questions I have seen are using the deprecated method presentModal but Xcode tells me to use this newer method presentViewController.  So does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  I must be missing something, but I can't for the life of me find out.  Thanks in advance on any insight to this matter!!!

Comment: One note, when I type [self presentView.....   Xcode does not autofill it in.  Is there somewhere that I need to set a delegate or something?

Answer (score 0):

May be you're missing the :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```